# How to access hiera data which is within a Puppet module

Tags: puppet, hiera

If I create a simple manifest and access the system defined hiera data, it works fine

```
$testvar=hiera('some var defined at system level')
notify { "Hiera message is $testvar":}
```

However, if I attempt to access data that is stored within some module ( downloaded from forge ) it does not

```
include some_module_from_forge
$testvar=hiera('some var defined in the modules hiera')
notify { "Hiera message is $testvar":}
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: There is a lot that could be going wrong here and you need to supply a lot more information. At a minimum, `hiera.yaml` for your global, env, and module need to be provided.

Comment: The hiera.yaml points to the data folder which contains common.yaml. My question is, does an "include <module_name>" suffice or do I need to do anything else.

Comment: The question would have been much clearer without the obfuscation of parameters to `hiera()`. Especially when using a Forge module, include the configuration & code or a link to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `lookup("module::param")` rather than the `hiera` function when using module data.

- [Function docs: lookup()](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/function.html#lookup)
- [Hiera: Using the lookup function](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/hiera_use_function.html)

Comment: Wonderful. That is what I was missing. I kept using hiera but it simply would not work !